# What is the name of the icon that comes up (red circle with a white horizontal line) when update fails?

Tags: updates, icons

Trying to get the name of the icon that appears in the left side of the upper right set of icons in the Ubuntu top panel or toolbar, when an update has failed? Red circle with a white horizontal line through the center.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[image]

This icon is `dialog-error.svg`. You can find the 64x64 file in the following folder:

```
/usr/share/icons/Humanity/status/64/dialog-error.svg
```

For a quick preview, open a terminal and type:

```
eog /usr/share/icons/Humanity/status/64/dialog-error.svg
```

Comment: I was actually looking for the name of the situation I guess. Like it was the "updated failed" icon. but I guess it would be said that dialog-error is being used to  reflect a failed update.